# My Pi noIR camera with additional IR led lighting gives me totally black picture

Tags: camera

During daylight the no ir camera is working correctly. But i wish to take photo during  the night o very low light I add a IR led lighting (850 mn) and suposedly strong enough but I get a black photo. is it needed a special config or parameter with raspistill ?
Or is it necessary to have a special IR lighing?

Comment: if you shine the led direct at camera do you get any white spots?

Answer (score 3):

The parameter is -ex night. IR led 850nm is correct. As ppumkin writes check IR led's function - if you see nothing, point to the cam with your TV's or similar remote controller - press a button on it and you should see light.